how to import styles correctly so that unit tests work in Angular?
I have a problem with unit test in angular. When i run ng test i have a errors with import scss.
This is an error:
./src/app/modules/auth/components/login/login.component.scss?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):     
Can't find stylesheet to import.
 @import "styles"

And this is a scss file:
    @import "styles";

   .login-container {
    @extend .center-page;
}

Styles.scss:
@import "node_modules/angular-notifier/styles";

@import "./utils/variables";
@import "./utils/extends";
@import "./utils/mixins";

I try to different ways to import style files.

You have a SCSS import issue.
Configure stylePreprocessorOptions in angular.json: Add the following to your angular.json to fix path resolution:
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src"
              ]
            }
            "scripts": []
          }
        }

This allows you to import SCSS files as if starting from the src directory, making paths like @import "styles"; valid
Here is an example:
  // src/app/app.component.scss
  // A relative path works
  @import '../style-paths/variables';

  // But now this works as well
  @import 'variables';


Thank, it solve a problem
